# just_audio shuffleIndicesStream gives wrong order

Tags: flutter, just-audio, audio-service

When I start to listen shuffleIndicesStream, it gives me empty list. Then, it gives me random indices list like [0, 5, 3, 1, 4, 2]. My playlist is not shuffling when it's created. I have player wrapper class called MyAuioHandler that extends audio_srvice's AudioHandler class.

I removed any shuffling methods, but the outputs was the same.

Comment: `[0, 5, 3, 1, 4, 2]` looks correct (i.e. shuffled), so do you mean the problem is the initial empty list?

Comment: No, Sir. The first time the shuffled indices list is given even though I do not set shuffle mode. After setting the shuffle mode manually, it gives me the correct values.

Comment: The values are given after giving an empty list.

Comment: "No, Sir." - So the empty list is NOT the problem? "The values are given after giving an empty list." - So the empty list IS the problem? I can't tell whether your answer to my question was Yes or No.

Comment: The problem is that shuffleIndicesStream is giving values [0, 5, 3, 1, 4, 2], even if I do not call the shuffle method. I am sorry for the bad question, if you do not understand it ).

Comment: So are you saying that you think it is wrong that shuffleIndices is giving you shuffled indices? What would you like it to give you instead?

Comment: Yes Sir. I think it should not give anything until I set shuffle mode manually, at least an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

`shuffleIndices` is defined as the indices generated by `shuffle()` whether or not shuffle mode is currently enabled.

`effectiveIndices` returns `shuffleIndices` if shuffle mode is enabled, otherwise returns the normal indices. You probably want something like that.

There is no direct stream for that, although there is one for `sequenceState` which you could map to what you want:

```dart
player.sequenceStateStream
    .map((state) => state.effectiveIndices)
    .distinct(IterableEquality().equals);
```

`IterableEquality` comes from the "collection" package.

Or, if you want to handle it within your own code, you can keep using `shuffleIndices` (or its stream) and just check if shuffle mode is enabled before you use it.